# How to add filters in power bi URL?

Tags: sql, url, filter, scope, powerbi

I tried all possible combinations and different syntax from google to filter using URL, but nothing is working.

Syntax: `?filter=Store/Territory eq 'NC'`
eg:

```
?filter=DimChannel/SurfaceName eq ' Swiftkey page - module'
?filter=DimChannel/SurfaceName eq ‘[MSCOM] Swiftkey - Hero module’
```

Comment: Is this really relate to SQL ?

Comment: nope. scope script